# How to convert special characters in utf-8 format while creating a xml file in ColdFusion

Tags: encoding, coldfusion, utf-8

I am using ColdFusion 5 and trying to convert special characters to utf-8 while creating xml file

I am using xmlFormat() for that, But when I parsing the xml file it is giving error like this:

> Parsing xml failed:
>
> mountainhomes/xdeadline_listings_wsj.xml:539: parser error : Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
>
> Bytes: 0x96 0x31 0x28 0x32
>
> 5BA,open kitchen,dining & family area w/gas log fp.Lower level has 2 garages
>
> Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â&n bsp;Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â  ^

Comment: Highly doubt you'll find anyone who can help you with an issue on CF 5.

Comment: CF 5 does indeed pose some challenges. Probably the easiest (although must time consuming) would be a UDF (could you do those in CF5?) that loops through common characters and does a `Replace`.

Comment: What _is_ the encoding of xdeadline_listings_wsj.xml ? Is it simply a proper declaration or a recode that is needed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UDF like Demoronize (http://www.cflib.org/index.cfm?event=page.udfbyid&udfid=725) to solve this. I use dpaste.org (Raw View) to find the offending character, get the proper ascii code, and add it to Demoronize to filter these garbage characters. Below are a list that I've added to the original UDF to take out Word quotes, elipses, etc.

```
text = Replace(text, Chr(96), "'", "All");
text = Replace(text, Chr(198), "'", "All");
text = Replace(text, Chr(8216), "'", "All");
text = Replace(text, Chr(8217), "'", "All");
text = Replace(text, Chr(8220), """", "All");
text = Replace(text, Chr(8221), """", "All");
text = Replace(text, Chr(8230), "...", "All");
text = Replace(text, Chr(244), """", "All");
text = Replace(text, Chr(246), """", "All");
text = Replace(text, Chr(8211), "-", "All");
```